# How do i properly Use a field to sort my array

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have an Array i will Like to sort with a field in the array But its not working

```
var data = [{tm: "09:00", tr: "30.34", rd: "73.23"},
{tm: "09:10", tr: "30.45", rd: "70.77"},
{tm: "09:50", tr: "29.95", rd: "75.70"},
{tm: "09:40", tr: "29.95", rd: "75.70"},
{tm: "01:50", tr: "29.95", rd: "75.70"},
{tm: "02:30", tr: "29.95", rd: "75.70"},
{tm: "04:50", tr: "29.95", rd: "75.70"},
{tm: "10:00", tr: "30.05", rd: "76.20"}];
```

i need to sort it with the tm field so the data will be in this format after sorting

```
0 tm: 01.50
1 tm: 02.30
2 tm: 04.50
3 tm: 09.00
4 tm: 09.10
5 tm: 09.40
6 tm: 09.50
7 tm: 10.00
```

i tried

```
data.sort(function(a, b){return a.tm - b.tm});
```

its not working Any help will be appreciated Thanks

Comment: `"09:00" - "09:10" == NaN`, you need to find a way to compare the values first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`a.tm - b.tm` would work if they are numbers. Because of `:` between them, `"09:10" - "09:50"` returns `NaN`.

So, You could [`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) the `:` and get just the numbers before subtracting `tm` values

```js
var data = [
    { tm: "09:00", tr: "30.34", rd: "73.23" },
    { tm: "09:10", tr: "30.45", rd: "70.77" },
    { tm: "09:50", tr: "29.95", rd: "75.70" },
    { tm: "09:40", tr: "29.95", rd: "75.70" },
    { tm: "01:50", tr: "29.95", rd: "75.70" },
    { tm: "02:30", tr: "29.95", rd: "75.70" },
    { tm: "04:50", tr: "29.95", rd: "75.70" },
    { tm: "10:00", tr: "30.05", rd: "76.20" }
  ];

data.sort((a, b) => +a.tm.replace(":", '') - +b.tm.replace(":", ''))

console.log(data)
```

Comment: Careful if you have any values around midnight, such as `00:10` - You wouldn't want `00:10` to evaluate as `>` `09:00`

Comment: Nice solution. I'll have to keep that one in mind for time calculations.

Comment: This is definitely very hacky. And you didnt include any explanation about why you are doing that or any justification

Comment: @Lewis in what situation would that happen?

Comment: @Lewis `0010 - 0900` is negative an will sort accordingly

Comment: @adiga Would the leading zeroes not be stripped? I.e, would it not evaluate as `10` - `9`?

Comment: @Lewis it will be `10 - 900`

Comment: @Marie What more explanation should I add here? I thought removing `:` and subtracting would be obvious here.

Comment: @Marie I'm sorry but I'm not understanding what you're upset with. Could you explain please? The replacement of the character allows for the string to be coerced into an integer when coming into contact with an arithmetic operator. As long as the format is consistent it will work the same every time. I'm not sure where you're getting that it doesn't work with every number?

Comment: @zfrisch  The only thing I can think is if running on old browsers, where `0300` would be interpreted as octal, so `"0300" - "0010" = 184` instead of `290`,  But I don't believe there are any current browsers even in none strict that will do this now.

Comment: @Keith I was actually wrong about my assumption but that is a good point. `0300` evaluates to `192`. Thankfully the implicit cast from string to number does not parse it as octal!

Answer (score 3):

`HH:MM` is intrinsically sort-able, so passing to localeCompare will work as expected.

```js
var data = [{tm: "09:00", tr: "30.34", rd: "73.23"},
{tm: "09:10", tr: "30.45", rd: "70.77"},
{tm: "09:50", tr: "29.95", rd: "75.70"},
{tm: "09:40", tr: "29.95", rd: "75.70"},
{tm: "01:50", tr: "29.95", rd: "75.70"},
{tm: "02:30", tr: "29.95", rd: "75.70"},
{tm: "04:50", tr: "29.95", rd: "75.70"},
{tm: "10:00", tr: "30.05", rd: "76.20"}];

data.sort((a, b) => a.tm.localeCompare(b.tm));

console.log(data)
```

Comment: Great use of `localeCompare`! Every time I see `locale` methods I get a little excited because they do seem to take care of common issues. Problem is that I hardly ever think of them.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot subtract a string, but you can compare if it's greater than.

You can sort by using `<`, `>`,`<=` or `>=`:

```js
var data = [{ tm: "09:00", tr: "30.34", rd: "73.23" },
    { tm: "09:10", tr: "30.45", rd: "70.77" },
    { tm: "09:50", tr: "29.95", rd: "75.70" },
    { tm: "09:40", tr: "29.95", rd: "75.70" },
    { tm: "01:50", tr: "29.95", rd: "75.70" },
    { tm: "02:30", tr: "29.95", rd: "75.70" },
    { tm: "04:50", tr: "29.95", rd: "75.70" },
    { tm: "10:00", tr: "30.05", rd: "76.20" }];
var d = data.sort(function (a, b) { return a.tm > b.tm; });
console.log(d);
```

**In response to comments about boolean comparison**

A better comparison method would be using [localeCompare](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) in `numeric` mode to compare values:

```js
var data = [{ tm: "09:00", tr: "30.34", rd: "73.23" },
    { tm: "09:10", tr: "30.45", rd: "70.77" },
    { tm: "09:50", tr: "29.95", rd: "75.70" },
    { tm: "09:40", tr: "29.95", rd: "75.70" },
    { tm: "01:50", tr: "29.95", rd: "75.70" },
    { tm: "02:30", tr: "29.95", rd: "75.70" },
    { tm: "04:50", tr: "29.95", rd: "75.70" },
    { tm: "10:00", tr: "30.05", rd: "76.20" }];
var d = data.sort(function (a, b) { return a.tm.localeCompare(b.tm, undefined, { numeric: true }); });
console.log(d);
```

**In response to comments about numeric localeCompare**

Numeric localeCompare will also be useful for numbers prefixed with `0`:

```js
var data = ["01", "10", "02"];
console.log({
    original: data,
    sorted: data.slice(0).sort(function (a, b) { return a.localeCompare(b, undefined, { numeric: true }); })
});
```

Comment: [Sorting in JavaScript: Shouldn't returning a boolean be enough for a comparison function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24080785)

Comment: `numeric` would be useful for `1,2,10`, but will have zero effect on `01,02,10`